# CORS issue POST/DELETE returning status:200 method:OPTIONS

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, heroku, cors, netlify

I'm having an issue doing a post request and a delete request from my react frontend to my heroku rails backend server using axios. My get request is working just find. I've tried doing both post and delete request on my postman and it works flawlessly. I'm not sure what the issue is.

My cors.rb

```
 Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do

    origins 'https://wondrous-speculoos-749189.netlify.app'
    # Specify the domain that is allowed to access your API

    resource '/api/*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
      credentials: true
  end
end
```

My react vite code

```
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [deletePlayerId, setDeletePlayerId] = useState('');


  const handlePlayerSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    console.log(firstName, lastName)
    const response = await axios.post('https://agile-reef-32463-2ad3559c3e00.herokuapp.com/players', {
      player: {
        first_name: firstName,
        last_name: lastName,
      },
    });
  
    // Reset form values
    setFirstName('');
    setLastName('');
     console.log(response.data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};


  const handleDeletePlayer = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      console.log(player.first_name);
      await axios.delete(`https://agile-reef-32463-2ad3559c3e00.herokuapp.com/players/${deletePlayerId}`);
      // Reset form values
      setDeletePlayerId('');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

I've tried cors.rb and still nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
The path in the resources of my cors.rb wasn't point correctly at the route. Instead of doing "/api/*", I replaced it with "/players/*". It worked instantly. I'm not sure why the GET fetch worked with /api/* though, but replacing that did the trick. Thank you!